# moodle - best place to put common logic

Tags: moodle

I got a method that should be used via blocks and modules, where should I put it,
do I need to require it in each class that uses it or there is a place moodle will automatically load and it's meant to use for this kind of cases? I'm looking for best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no official place for common third party libraries like that, but you could use the /local folder, which is as close as you'll get. Documentation [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins) explains how to make a local plugin, which in your case needs to be non-functional, so just have a basic version.php file and lib.php with your stuff in it. Your module and block can then use require_once() to make sure the lib.php file from /local is included.